# MOSFET voltage is opposite from what I expect

Tags: mosfet, ltspice

I have this circuit on LTspice.

The voltage from the 12V seems to rise when the 5V is falling.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There suppose to invert. at the drain but if you see the voltage across the R the current is positive logic

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* Nothing, OK except for your **expectation** of how the circuit behaves versus how it actually behaves. So you only need to try and "re-understand" how the circuit operates.

Comment: Try explaining why you seem to think that the drain voltage (what you call the "voltage from the 12V" should rise when V1 does.

Comment: @EliKonky I'm a moderator here. I look at discussions like this and TRY to decide what is best for all concerned. I hope that all will be 'happy'. That certainly includes the question asker (you in this case). People here are generally helpful BUT their methods vary. Some will hand you answers on a platter - others ty to help you by encouraging you to help yourself.  The latter approach tends to be more annoying BUT is also generally reasonably productive long term to learning. I suggest you try to ignore the annoying aspects while noting advice from people with vast experience.

Comment: I have copied ALL comments to chat and deleted ones here that are less technically relevant - whol;e commenty list here if of interest -> [Here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118009/discussion-on-question-by-eli-konky-mosfet-voltage-is-opposite-from-what-i-expec).

Comment: @Russell the comment provided by aka was in no way productive. I hope he will avoid sending people to google next time. And thank you for deleting those unfriendly comments

Comment: @EliKonky fwiw I consider Andy's comment 'somewhat helpful'. Saying "Google it" alone is valueless. Suggesting WHAT to Google (even if obvious in retrospect) can be useful. All the comments are still available in chat , if anyone cares -  Andy's and yours and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you should get.

If V1 is 0V M1 is turned off so R1 pulls the output up to 12V.
In this state imagine the circuit without M1 present all you have is R1 connected to 12V. There is no current through the resistor so the output has to be 12V

If v1 is 5V M1 is turned on and pulls the output down to 0V.
In this state imagine that M1 is replaced with a short circuit from Drain to Source.

Comment: Thanks. So I got this all wrong. So my intuition was all wrong? Say I replace the resistor with a dc motor I will need to decrease the pwm on time in order to increase the voltage across the motor? Or am i still missing some key understanding here?

Comment: @EliKonky - no you've still got it wrong, but in a different way. The voltage you measure at the drain pin of the MOSFET is not the voltage across the load (either R1 or your proposed motor). When you measure the voltage at the drain you're measuring from there to your circuit's ground node - but your load is not connected to ground, it's connected to +12V. The circuit you have there is exactly what you need to PWM your motor.

Comment: @brhans thank you. I think I got it now. I spent hours trying to get my head around this.